# Invalid : E:\Jenkins\workspace\XXX.dll Has no TestFixtures

Tags: msbuild, nunit-3.0

When trying to run nunit3-console.exe on my testing dll project on jenkins machine

I'm Getting Invalid : E:\Jenkins\workspace\XXX.Tests.dll
**Has no TestFixtures**

the dll was created by jenkins using msbuild.exe

on my dev machine machine it works perfectly using the build from Visual studio

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that i had another testing project in the solution with an older version of nunit
and on jenkins it was building the solution and copying the binaries to the same folder 
making the nunit.framework.xml to be overwritten 
the solution was making sure that both project referenced the latest nunit version.